# JS alert after all content is loaded

Tags: javascript

I need to make an alert after all content is loaded and user can see all images 100%.

I do this way - I made a function in the end of my webpage (be fore the BODY tag is closed:

```
window.onload=function(){
  alert("This is my alert text");
}
```

But it doesnot work. The alert comes when some images are not loaded. Especially on mobile devices. On desktop it works sometimes

Comment: Just see it with my eyes. I want see all my content - and after alert - why it can pause it if it should run after it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.readyState); // check for more states
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        alert("Everything loaded now including images, scripts and styles.");
    }
});
```

Please check @ CodePen
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/07c67507a741a76f4ae208d52a29cf7b/

^ I have added big images for you in the example. Alert will show up only after everything is fully loaded.

Comment: seems it work - Thanks a lot. gonna test now on moblie devices

Comment: No problem @mrdeath4. Please upvote when it solves your problem.

Comment: ok. and one more question it will also wait till all javascript code loads too ?

Comment: @mrdeath4 : Yes my friend. It will absolutely wait for everything.

Answer (score -4):

Try waiting for the images to load themselves .. like so

```
$('img').load(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
})
```

Comment: this is not related to jQuery in any way.

Comment: it's related to a script running before the images are shown, it won't kill him to use jQuery i think, am i right or right ?

Comment: No, it won't kill him. At the same time it won't kill you to update your JS skills and move on from jQuery. [Other](https://githubengineering.com/removing-jquery-from-github-frontend/) [projects](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/12/3/this-week-in-rails-jquery-no-longer-part-of-rails-and-more/) did this years ago.

Comment: I got the necessary skills that i need, and i answered a question the way i could, not ur business after all to tell me what skills to improve or how to answer a question, after all i did it to help ..

Comment: Ignoring all the other faults of this answer, this would trigger every time each image on the page completes loading. The OP wants it to trigger once, after everything has loaded.