# JavaScript (Alert Message)

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have written a JavaScript alert message code it displays the alert message first in both codes 1 and 2  before Html content. What should I do to run the HTML content first and then a javascript code?

**Code 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World !</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am learning JavaScript.</h1>
        <div id="Content">
            <p>This is a paragraph tag. Here the content of html.</p>
        </div>
        <script src="text.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World !</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am learning JavaScript.</h1>
        <div id="Content">
            <p>This is a paragraph tag. Here the content of html.</p>
        </div>
        <script>
alert(" This is alert message.");
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In both examples the script runs after the HTML content. You should be able to see the header on the page behind the alert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS alert after all content is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570559/js-alert-after-all-content-is-loaded)

Answer (score 3):

There is a `load` event, which will fire AFTER the page is loaded. You can listen to the event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets are loaded');
    alert ("This is an alert MSG");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` for this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World !</title>
        </head>
        <body>

          <h1>I am learning JavaScript.</h1>

          <div id="Content">
             <p>This is a paragraph tag. Here the content of html.</p>
          </div>

        <script>
         setTimeout(()=>{
           alert(" This is alert message.")     
          },2000)

        </script>
      
      </body>
  
   </html>
```

Comment: Don't. Waiting 2 seconds then popup an alert message will surprise the visitors.

Comment: Hahaha ! lets reduce it to 1 sec.

Comment: this is an incorrect solution. You cannot guarantee all page elements are loaded in a specific period.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code just put defer attribute as below

```
<script defer src="text.js"></script>
```

A script that will be downloaded in parallel to parsing the page, and executed after the page has finished parsing

for more detail refer to the URL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Try not to refer to an unofficial source: w3schools. Refer to MDN instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onload` function. This function called after body load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World !</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am learning JavaScript.</h1>
        <div id="Content">
            <p>This is a paragraph tag. Here the content of html.</p>
        </div>
        <script>
        window.onload = function () { 
            alert(" This is alert message.");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

create your Script like below

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  
            function displayalert() {  
  
  
               alert ("This is an alert MSG");  
            }  
      </script>
```

add this code in your body(this is a button)

```
<input type = "button" value = "Click me" onclick = "displayalert();" />
```

when you click on this button you will see the alert
We are using the onclick attribute and call the displayalert() function where the alert() is defined.